# Component link is not resolved for a field with "_self" annotation in combination with dynamic component presentation (DXA 2.0.3 Java, SDL Web 8.5)

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, dxa2.2

I have two different view model for the same schema, one view is to display a *Summary* page and other view is meant for a *Details* page.

1. Summary page displays dynamic component presentations, which are
   retrieved by using `getEntityModel` method of DXA
   [DefaultContentProvider](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/release/2.0/dxa-framework/dxa-tridion-provider/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/tridion/mapping/impl/DefaultContentProvider.java).
2. Detail page displays a regular static component presentation.

On Summary page, I want to display a (resolved) link to a detail page for every Component presentation, to achieve this I've added a field 'url' with annotation **_self** as described on [SDL docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-05E61C0C-6755-4875-ABBF-13EFC67CC8A8).

My Entity view model is defined as follows:

```
public class MyArticle extends AbstractEntityModel {
    private String titel;
    private RichTekst intro;
    private Date date;
    @SemanticProperty("_self")
    private String url;   
}
```

My both views are displayed as expected, except I encounter a following issue:

On my *Summary* view, `url` field is empty as component link is not resolved/populated in my entity model (I can verify this in a debug mode). Other fields of the DCP do get populated and displayed as expected.

Whereas *Details* view with static component presentation can display `url` with resolved link(but obviously I don't need a resolved link here as I'm already on this page).

It seems like semantic property **_self** is not being recognized for the dynamic component presentations.

Or am I missing anything? any thoughts?

**Update:**
Below is `EntityModelData` values retrieved from the DXA Model Service:

[image: EntityModeData values]

As it can beeb seen, linkUrl is also empty.

Comment: Can you provide the DXA R2 Data Model as retrieved from the DXA Model Service for both scenarios? In particular: I’m interested in the presence of an `EntityModelData.LinkUrl` property; this property is used to map Component Links, including the `_self` mapping.

Comment: I have added screenshot with data from the DXAModel Service, LInkUrl is also empty here.

Comment: Wow, some delayed feedback! :-)  So, if I understand correctly, the `linkUrl` (and `url` property on your View Model) is properly set when reading a CP in context of a Page, but not when reading a DCP separately using a `getEntityModel` call?

Comment: well, the issue became irrelevant due to implementation changes. However, for some other project it is once again relevant - hence the delay in the response :)
To answer your question, I have not tested with the page context but it is definitely the case with the DCPs (using indeed ```getEntityModel```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the DXA Model Service/Extension only sets `EntityModelData.linkUrl` for linked Components (nested Entity Models). However, when this property is not set, the DXA Web Application Framework should use the CD link resolving API to resolve the link.

If I look at the DXA.NET implementation (which I'm most familiar with), I see it checks if `EntityModelData.LinkUrl` is `null` to determine whether the property is set by the DXA Model Service/Extension or not.  However, looking at your screenshot, it seems it returns an empty string instead of `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In other words, it is a bug in DXA Framework, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, or in DXA Model Service/Extension.  At least, there seems to be a mismatch between the two.